# Adding routes for actions that operate on one record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I want to create a method in my rails app that will increase a value tied to a record.

The method in the controller looks like this:

```
def upvote
  @spot = Spot.find(params[:id])
  @spot.rating += 1

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @spot }
  end
end
```

Then when viewing the record at "spots/1" I include this code:

```
<%= link_to 'Upvote', @spot, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :upvote %>
```

Which, when clicked, throws the error:

```
"No route matches "/spots/1""
```

Even though I'm already at /spots/1.  I know this is a routes issue, but I can't seem to give this method a route that works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `:method` identifies the HTTP verb (GET, POST, UPDATE, ...), not the method to be called.

To add a new action, edit the routes.rb file

```
resources :sposts do
  member do
    put :upvote
  end
end
```

Then use a named route

```
<%= link_to 'Upvote', upvote_spot_path(@spot), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :put %>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I did have to use post instead of put, but that worked great.